# Difference bewteen using shell command "command time -v" and C function "getrusage"?

Tags: c, shell, memory

I want to know the Maximum resident set size of a the execution of a shell file (which is launching C program).
Is there any difference of result between those two solutions :

- command time -v ./file.sh
- calling getrusage() function in my C program

I tried both and it seems clearly similar to me ... but I would like approval :)

Comment: I've never heard of _command time_ before as a shell command; I Googled for it and don't find anything. Would you mind linking me to a source that explains it? Thanks :]

Comment: @8protons `command` is a built-in command for real. Check out `man command`.

Comment: @cad Thanks dude. I Googled _man command_ and not one actual man page popped up! lol just instructions on how to use the `man` command haha

Comment: (I don't have a Linux box near me at the moment to actually do `man command`)

Comment: @8protons [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), search for `command [-pVv] command [arg ...] `.

Comment: Do you know if the two method give always the same result?